# Skype not loading from MS store on Win10

Tags: windows-10, skype

I have been having no success in loading skype from the Win-Store on Win-10.
FYI: Skype works on the skype web portal, as well as on an older exe version of skype.

When I launch skype from the online store, it shows the blue screen for about 2 secs and disappears. When I look at the task-Mgr, processes I dont see skype. The app from the store used to work before, but stopped about 2-3 weeks back.

Things I have tried:

- Un-install skype app, rebooted my PC and re-installed app. No success.
- Tried, repair, terminate, reset of the app and rebooted PC. No success.
- Tried sfc /scannow to find any corrupted files. No success.
- tried MS support, no help there

Any leads on what else I can try troubleshooting?

@mod: If this is a wrong place for this question, please move it to the appropriate forum.

Tx in advance

Comment: Do other UWP applications work on your system?

Comment: It does. It looks like a skype only package issue. I contacted the MS community and one of the gentleman gave me a windows script to uninstall and re-install. Uninstall 
Windows Key+X > Windows Powershell (Admin) > Copy the below, paste into Powershell
Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.SkypeApp | Remove-AppxPackage 

Reinstall 
Copy and paste below and Enter 

Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.SkypeApp | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}

Comment: Script isn’t necessary.  You could have gone to the Windows Store and just uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer thread on MS:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/sk_else-sk_other/skype-not-loading-from-ms-store-on-win10/803675ed-d866-49dc-beee-db682521c2e9?messageId=2831d0ef-b181-4be9-b910-5b280ed59679

Uninstall and reinstall Skype app (Note - You will not lose any Skype data because of this)

Uninstall 
Windows Key+X > Windows Powershell (Admin) > Copy the below, paste into Powershell > Enter

Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.SkypeApp | Remove-AppxPackage

Reinstall 
Copy and paste below and Enter

Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.SkypeApp | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}